# PS1 from .bashrc overridden somewhere else

Tags: bash, command-line, bashrc

I'm trying to use a custom PS1 line, including colors and git repo information, on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 machine. I have a predefined version I'm successfully using on other systems running Ubuntu or Mint.

In my `.bashrc`, I added the following part at the bottom:

```
# Colors
Black='\e[0;30m'        # Black
Red='\e[0;31m'          # Red
...
NC="\e[m"               # Color Reset

# show git branch
parse_git_branch() {
  # git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^\[^*\]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/|\1/'
  git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | sed 's/^/|/g'
}
PS1="\[$Green\]\u@\h \[$BBlack\]\w\[$Yellow\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$NC\] $ "
```

However, when opening a terminal, I still see the default PS1 line. A `echo $PS1` prints `\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]\u@\h:\w>`. Apparently, this variable gets overridden somewhere. But where, or how can I find this out?

By the way, `.bashrc` definitely gets executed. I verified this by adding a line like `echo "hello"` and seeing the result when opening a terminal.

**Update**

Running `bash -x` prints a lot of output, ending with

```
+ On_White='\e[47m'
+ NC='\e[m'
+ PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[1;30m\]\w\[\e[0;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[m\] $ '
++ PS1='\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]\u@\h:\w> '
```

**Update II**

Output of `grep -H PS1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`:

```
/home/myself/.bashrc:# this does not apply, but PS1 env var is empty.
/home/myself/.bashrc:[ -n "$PS1" ] || INTERACTIVE=0
/home/myself/.bashrc:PS1="\[$Green\]\u@\h \[$BBlack\]\w\[$Yellow\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$NC\] $ "
/etc/profile.d/company.sh:  linux:root) PS1="\u@\h:\w# "; TMOUT=3600 ;;
/etc/profile.d/company.sh:  linux:*)    PS1="\u@\h:\w> " ;;
/etc/profile.d/company.sh:  *:root)     PS1="\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]\u@\h:\w# "; TMOUT=3600 ;;
/etc/profile.d/company.sh:  *)          PS1="\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]\u@\h:\w> " ;;
/etc/profile.d/company.sh:export PS1
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh:  [ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

**Update III**

My full `.bashrc`:

```
PKG_ROOT=/opt/companyhome/

NFS_ROOT=/share/install/companyhome/current/

LINKS_VERSION=3.0.0.0

# write to stdout (disabled for non interactive (e.g. scp) logins)
print_msg() {
    if  [ "$INTERACTIVE" = "1" ]; then
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

print_msg_debug(){
    if [[ ! -z "$COMPANYHOME_INIT_DEBUG" ]]; then
        print_msg "$@"
    fi;
}

# check if this is an interactive session.
# tty results with 1 if not terminal. But with ansible remote execution,
# this does not apply, but PS1 env var is empty.
INTERACTIVE=1
tty -s || INTERACTIVE=0 
[ -n "$PS1" ] || INTERACTIVE=0


print_msg_debug "loading companyhome"

# define_companyhome_root
# check if we run against a packaged version or a nfs (legacy) version of companyhome 
CURRENT_ROOT=""
if [ -d "$PKG_ROOT" ]; then
    CURRENT_ROOT=$PKG_ROOT
elif [ -d "$NFS_ROOT" ]; then
    CURRENT_ROOT=$NFS_ROOT
else 
    print_msg "Error no companyhome installation found."
    print_msg "Companyhome could not be loaded."
    return 1
fi 

export "COMPANYHOME_ROOT=$CURRENT_ROOT"
print_msg_debug "companyhome is installed in \"$CURRENT_ROOT\""

# include companyhome
. "${COMPANYHOME_ROOT}/update/check_linksversion"
. "${COMPANYHOME_ROOT}/bashrc_company"

if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi



    # Normal Colors
Black='\e[0;30m'        # Black
Red='\e[0;31m'          # Red
Green='\e[0;32m'        # Green
Yellow='\e[0;33m'       # Yellow
Blue='\e[0;34m'         # Blue
Purple='\e[0;35m'       # Purple
Cyan='\e[0;36m'         # Cyan
LightGray='\e[0;37m'    # Light Gray

# Bold
BBlack='\e[1;30m'       # Black
BRed='\e[1;31m'         # Red
BGreen='\e[1;32m'       # Green
BYellow='\e[1;33m'      # Yellow
BBlue='\e[1;34m'        # Blue
BPurple='\e[1;35m'      # Purple
BCyan='\e[1;36m'        # Cyan
BWhite='\e[1;37m'       # White

# Background
On_Black='\e[40m'       # Black
On_Red='\e[41m'         # Red
On_Green='\e[42m'       # Green
On_Yellow='\e[43m'      # Yellow
On_Blue='\e[44m'        # Blue
On_Purple='\e[45m'      # Purple
On_Cyan='\e[46m'        # Cyan
On_White='\e[47m'       # White

NC="\e[m"               # Color Reset


# show git branch
parse_git_branch() {
  # git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^\[^*\]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/|\1/'
  git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | sed 's/^/|/g'
}
PS1="\[$Green\]\u@\h \[$BBlack\]\w\[$Yellow\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$NC\] $ "
```

`${COMPANYHOME_ROOT}/bashrc_company` :

```
INTERACTIVE=1
tty -s || INTERACTIVE=0 
[ -n "$PS1" ] || INTERACTIVE=0

# is_nfs_home returns 0 (success) if /home is nfs/network based, else 1 (local home)  
# the function does not guarantee the accessibility
is_nfs_home(){
    # if $HOME is an explicit mount -> nfs else its local
--
        export PS2='> '
    fi
}
sp () {
    setps2
    export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=`echo "\u@\h$PS2"`'
    export PS1
}
dp () {
    setps2
    if [ "$TERM" = "dtterm" ] || [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ] || [ "$TERM" = "xterm-color" ] || [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
        export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="\[\033]0;\u@\h: \w\007\]\u@\h:\w$PS2"'
    elif [ "$TERM" = "sun-cmd" ] || [ ! -z $EMACS ] ; then
        export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=`echo "\u@\h:\w$PS2"`'
    else
        sp
    fi
    export PS1
}

dp
export ignoreeof=0
```

Comment: Run `bash -x`. The output might be a bit much, but it should hint at what's happening.

Comment: Please post the output of `grep -H PS1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @muru Thanks, I updated the question. To me, this looks like `PS1` is indeed being overridden, or what exactly does the output say?

Comment: That a file is being sourced within `.bashrc`, and it is setting `PS1`.

Comment: @terdon Done. Looks interesting; I suppose `company.sh` overrides it then, right?

Comment: If it does, then it is very weird. Files in `profile.d` should be sourced by `/etc/profile`, which should be sourced before `.bashrc`.

Comment: That's odd. That shouldn't happen unless your `~/.profile` is sourcing `.bashrc`. Is it? How are you logging in to the machine? Is this over `ssh`?

Comment: There is no `~/.profile` here. No, I'm sitting in front of the real machine. However, I know little about the setup in detail, as it was done by my company. It might be highly customized.

Comment: OK, to give you a definitive answer, we'll need to see the contents of your `~/.bashrc`. Is it sourcing `~/profile` or `/etc/profile`? Is it sourcing `company.sh`? We can't help unless we see all relevant files and find which one is calling `company.sh`.

Comment: That's really strange. Since you're setting PS1 at the very end of the file, that sjould overwrite anything set before it. Yet, your `bash -x` output shows that it's set to your desired value and then overwritten. Curiouser and curiouser. Could you come into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) so we can discuss this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line in your `${COMPANYHOME_ROOT}/bashrc_company` file:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=`echo "\u@\h$PS2"`'
```

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable defines a command that should be run before a prompt is shown. In your case, this has been set to setting PS1. So, each time a prompt is shown, your PS1 is being reset to the dwefault value.

I have no idea why anyone would want to do this, but it's simple enough to fix. Either delete that line from `${COMPANYHOME_ROOT}/bashrc_company` or set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to something else in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=""
```

Comment: Wow, that solved it, thank you very much! I chose the second solution, as I was afraid to fiddle around in a 2000-line script (`bashrc_company`, yes it's that big) from someone else...

Comment: Changing `PS1` in `PROMPT_COMMAND` makes sense when you want to the prompt to depend on dynamic information such as the current directory or the previously executed command. Here it would make sense if `setps2` (not shown) sets `PS2` to value that isn't constant in a given shell instance.